# Extracting information from Strings

Tags: regex, go

When given a string of the form `https://website-name.some-domain.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId` (type 1) or `https://website-name.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId?randomContent` (type 2), I need to extract out only two sub-strings. I need the `website-name` in one string and `resourceId` in an other string.

I have extracted the website name using the following code:

```
s := "https://website-name.some-domain.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId?randomContent"
w := regexp.MustCompile("https://(.*?)\\.")
website := w.FindStringSubmatch(s)
fmt.Println(website[1])
```

I have the other regex to get the resourceId

```
s := "https://website-name.some-domain.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId?randomContent"
r := regexp.MustCompile("com/(.*?)\\?")
resource := r.FindStringSubmatch(s)
fmt.Println(resource[1])
```

This works for any string that ends with `?` or `?randomContent`. But I have strings that don't have a trailing `?` and I am not able to work with such cases (type 1).

I tried `"(com/(.*?)\\?)|(com/(.*?).*)"` to get `resourceId` which is of no use.

I am not able to find an elegant way to extract these two sub-strings.

Note: The `randomContent` is an arbitrarily long substring, the same goes for the `resourceId` as well. But the `resourceId` will not have `?` in it. Upon encountering a `?`, it can be said that the `resourceId` has ended.

Also, `website-name` can differ, but the pattern is the same - An arbitrary sub-domain and a `.com` will be present in the string.

Here is what I have tried: https://play.golang.org/p/MGQIT5XRuuh

Comment: Can the downvoter please say why the question is bad?

Comment: Check https://play.golang.org/p/55ExIDxmL5z, does it work as expected?

Comment: I can only assume about the down vote, but instead of making it easy to answer your question (or just identify it, for that matter) you make it complicated.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I guess that too. The question may seem verbose. I just wanted to give the complete picture anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample strings you show are ordinary HTTPS URLs, so you can use the [`net/url`](https://godoc.org/net/url) package to parse them.  The `website-name` is the first part of the `parsedUrl.Hostname()`, and the `resourceId` is the `parsedUrl.Path` less a leading `/`.

```
u, err := url.Parse(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
host := u.Hostname()
first := strings.SplitN(host, ".", 2)[0]
fmt.Printf("website-name: %s\n", first)
fmt.Printf("resourceId: %s\n", u.Path[1:])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fnF2RTBuFxR has a complete example, including the two URL strings from the question.  This works even if the hostname part of the URL doesn't end with `.com`, or the path part includes that string, or there is a port number or hash fragment, or other variations.

Comment: Best answer. Go comes with a native package for doing exactly this.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since it is generic and also solves my problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something as simple as this will help.

You can extract the *website name* using the following regex and returning the first group:

```
//([^/.]+)

//         start with //
([^/.]+)   match anything until first dot
```

You can extract the *resourceId* using the following regex and also returning first group:

```
.com/([^/?]+)

.com/      start with .com
([^/?]+)   match everything until the first ? (if exists, else matches till end)
```

[Link to Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nI3XTHFB-dq)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this expression might work:

```
(?i)https?:\/\/(www\.)?([^.]*)[^\/]*\/([^?\r\n]*)
```

#### Test

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(?i)https?:\/\/(www\.)?([^.]*)[^\/]*\/([^?\r\n]*)`)
    var str = `https://website-name.some-domain.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId?randomContent

https://website-name.some-domain.some-sub-domain.com/resourceId`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ6tTf/1/)